# Predict clusters from data using Spark MLlib KMeans

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have generated my cluster centers from  features of my data say 'Kmeans.data.txt' as you find in

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt

This was performed using KMeans in Spark MLib.

```
clusters.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

Any idea how to predict the clusters derived from this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excerpt from the KMean MLlib clustering code snippet  retrieved from  [Scala Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-clustering.html)

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))

// Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 20
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)

// here is what I added to predict data points that are within the clusters
clusters.predict(parsedData).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple, if you read the [KmeansModel's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel), you will notice that it has two constructors, one of them:

> new KMeansModel(clusterCenters: Array[Vector])

Therefore, you can instantiate an object having `KMeans`' centroids. I show an example below.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
  Vectors.dense(Array(-0.1, 0.0, 0.0)), 
  Vectors.dense(Array(9.0, 9.0, 9.0)), 
  Vectors.dense(Array(3.0, 2.0, 1.0))))

val centroids = Array(
  Vectors.dense(Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), 
  Vectors.dense(Array(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)),
  Vectors.dense(Array(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)),
  Vectors.dense(Array(9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),
  Vectors.dense(Array(9.1, 9.1, 9.1)),
  Vectors.dense(Array(9.2, 9.2, 9.2)))

val model = new KMeansModel(clusterCenters=centroids)

model.predict(rdd).take(10)

// res13: Array[Int] = Array(0, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks.  In the example you gave, I am not clear about the centroids you defined because the KMean model helps to first determine the cluster center from the data points and then I have asked  how to obtain the  clusters while performing the prediction on the parsed data.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, `KMeans` is the class that actually trains the model and returns a `KMeansModel` object, so if you already have the centroids you can instantiate the model by using one of its constructors.

Comment: @user844518 I mean do you want to find the number of ks? I'm very confused.